# Memory Usage per Character for each MySQL Collation

Tags: mysql, memory, memory-management, character, collation

Is there somewhere a good bundled documentation of all the different MySQL collations? I mean an overview that also includes memory usage per character (dynamic/static size) and type of characters that can be stored in each single collation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Collation" has no impact on size.  "Character set" does.  Here are some answers:

- ascii, binary, latin1, latin2, etc -- 1 character = 1 byte.
- big5, euc*, *jis, hebrew, etc -- 1 character = 2 bytes.
- utf8 -- 1 character = 1 or 2 or 3 bytes.  Generally, 1 byte for English, 2 for other Western European characters, 3 for Asian.  [More details](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#diagnosing_charset_issues)
- utf8mb4 -- 1 character = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 bytes.  It is utf8, plus Emoji and some more Chinese characters.

`utf8mb4` can store virtually every known character in the world.  And it is evolving as we speak.

`ascii` (7-bit) is a subset of most (not all) other character sets.

[Collation vs Character set](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#basic_concepts)

"All the different collations" -- The answer is evolving, and it depends on what version of MySQL you are running.  Run `SHOW COLLATION;`.  In 5.6.12, I see 219 collations across a few dozen character sets.

[The Reference Manual Chapter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset.html)

`VARCHAR(10)` will take 2-32 bytes (2 for length), depending on the text in it.  '0123456789' will take only 12 bytes in a `VARCHAR`.

`CHAR(10)` utf8 will always consume 30 bytes.  It is a common mistake to use `CHAR` and the default `utf8`, thereby wasting lots of space.

What more would you like to know?